# Changing value in Firebase results in infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement a function of 'add to favorite' by clicking in a star (button). When i click for the first time, set a value to user favorite in firebase and the star will be yellow, and when i click again, it removes from list, and star back to normal. I'm tryin' this code, but is looping. How can i solve this?

```
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Usuarios" );
    ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" )
            .addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        botaoFavorito.setImageResource(  R.drawable.ic_favoritos  );
                        ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue(null);
         
                    }
              else {
                        botaoFavorito.setImageResource(  R.drawable.ic_favorito_adicionado  );
                        ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue(posicao);
                       
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.

- `addValueEventListener` - which goes on listing events **continuously**.
- `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`- listens for the very
  **first event only**.

In your code, just replace`addValueEventListener` with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, that's all, leave the reamaining portion of the code intact.

Comment: This is just a less-detailed version of [the accepted answer that was posted much earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844732/208273).

Comment: Frank van Puffelen gave some extra info which is irrelevant and also rewrite its code. I just tell things in simplest way and what he needs to change in his code. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're calling `addValueEventListener`, Firebase calls your `onDataChange` with the current data as quickly as possible, and then keeps monitoring the database for changes. Whenever there is a change, it calls your `onDataChange` again, with the updated data.

In your `onDataChange` implement, you modify the data by calling `setValue`. Since that data is under the location you're listening on, it triggers the listener, which calls your `onDataChange` again. So you get a loop of `onDataChange` -> `setValue` -> `onDataChange` -> `setValue`....

The simplest solution is to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which only gets the initial value and doesn't keep listening. So with that you get `onDataChange` -> `setValue` and nothing more.

In code:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Usuarios" );
ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" )
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                botaoFavorito.setImageResource(  R.drawable.ic_favoritos  );
                ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue(null);
 
            }
      else {
                botaoFavorito.setImageResource(  R.drawable.ic_favorito_adicionado  );
                ref.child( mAuth.getUid() ).child( "Favoritos" ).child( posicao ).setValue(posicao);
               
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    } );
```